# Are "Cauchy's linear partial differential equations" and the "Cauchy problem" the same thing?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

My teacher asked me to write a report about **Cauchy's linear partial differential equations**. I couldn't find any sources about this subject. The only sources I could find talk about the [Cauchy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_problem). Is this the same subject that my teacher meant?

Comment: It seems your teacher is the only one who can actually answer this question.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say the equations being described are probably the Cauchy-Riemann equations.